# Automatically hide Widgets that would lengthen page

Tags: widgets, sidebar

Something I've been dreaming about ever since I started using CMS's for making websites. I've settled on WP now, so hence I'm asking here.

I conditionally hide widgets on certain pages that are very short, where the widgets extend the page too much, leaving lots of blank space in the main content area at the bottom.

It would be much nicer to have a sidebar which dynamically hides widgets that would otherwise lengthen the page.

As a bonus, maybe I could even prioritize which widgets to hide (as opposed to merely the bottom ones).

Maybe it would be done by making the sidebar inherit its length from the main content, regardless of whether all the widgets then fit. Then something like CSS could be used to hide widgets that don't fit into the sidebar div?

Comment: You would have to do this with Javascript as the PHP has no idea how "long" the page is. That makes this a pure Javascript question which is are off topic per the [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Maybe try [so].

Comment: Have you considered using more than one sidebar rather than a single sidebar that appears everywhere?

Comment: Well, to counter @s_ha_dum's argument, you could determine the length in characters, of `the_content()` and go off of that. But that's not a very definitive examination since images can have height too. But then, images could also be examined...

Comment: You can get character count but not screen/window width or zoom level or any number of other necessary bits of information. Our designers have asked for this kind of magic 20 different times. The best you get with PHP is a very bad guess.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Basically a decent implementation requires JS. I'll ask on Stack Overflow :)